# Github better network graph

Tags: git, github

recently Github changed the way that the Network's graph is shown.

In our company we really like to follow it to have an idea of what is going on and those changes really changed the way that we visualize the graph.

I did some research, try a few ways but now it seems that GitHub closed the doors to get the network info easy.

So, do you guys know if there is a way of getting the network graph like an embedded-able element or change the page html/css so we can have the canvas element bigger without messing the graph itself or something like that?

The end goal is to have a better/bigger picture of the graph.

Thanks

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but have you taken a look at `gitk` to see if it solves any of your visualization needs?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a way to change the graph from github, not generating one by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try making use of this JavaScript snippet against a project's "network/members" page.

https://gist.github.com/starlocke/a617f32e5ca23f0a4c6a

1. Inject jQuery onto GitHub, somehow. (I use the *CJS* extension for **Chrome** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija; and *Custom Style Script* for **Firefox** https://mybrowseraddon.com/custom-style-script.html)
2. Launch a Developer Console (F12, possibly; depends on your platform)
3. Copy/Paste the Javascript Gist.

RESULT: You'll get output similar to this (minor cleaning up may be needed):

```
git remote add davidkuridza https://github.com/davidkuridza/git-appraise-web.git
git remote add digideskio https://github.com/digideskio/git-appraise-web.git
git remote add Happy-Ferret https://github.com/Happy-Ferret/git-appraise-web.git
git remote add promet https://github.com/promet/git-appraise-web.git
git remote add sokolovstas https://github.com/sokolovstas/git-appraise-web.git
git remote add sxiaoming2007 https://github.com/sxiaoming2007/git-appraise-web.git
```

4. `git clone` the repository of interest (assuming you're using a Terminal/Console)

Shell:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/git-appraise-web.git
```

5. `cd` into its directory.

Shell:

```
cd git-appraise-web
```

6. Copy/Paste the "RESULT" `console.log()` output from Step 3, into the Terminal/Console (**NOTE**: minor cleanup may be required; move it to a notepad first).
7. `git fetch --all` to update the new "remote repositories".
8. Launch a "GUI" graph view, such as `git graph` (https://sites.google.com/site/sudokillall9/articles/gitgraphvariants) or `gitk`.
9. Explore to your heart's content, paying attention to the various "remote origins".
10. ???
11. Profit :D

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but like I said, I'm looking for a way to change the github canvas element, not to generate a graph using a different tool ;)

Comment: No worries. The effort was produced "a long time ago". You could always take this foundation and build it up by filling the blank of step 10 to find a way to make leverage the "full graph" created using command-line tools to build your own replacement for the GitHub canvas :P Of course, that project would take **much more** effort, though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a userscript for GitHub network page: https://github.com/maliayas/github-network-ninja

Basically it provides:

- Full-viewport network graph.
- Searchable commit list.

[Click on the image for full size.]
[image: github-network-search.png]